# How to access webpages running in Raspberry Pi through Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi3, asp.net-webpages, httpapi

There's a webpage running on my Raspberry Pi. I want to access it through a button in a Unity Project. When I click on the button in Unity, it should redirect to the webpage running in Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `Application.OpenURL()` method, like this:

```
void ButtonPressed() {
    Application.OpenURL("http://serverip/page.html");
}
```

This will open a browser window of the url.